# What siddur do the Mountain Jews use?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, prayer-book, nuschaot

What siddur do the [Mountain Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Jews) use and how does it differ from mainstream Sephardi nusach?

Comment: I'd assume something similar to the Bukharian nusach.

Comment: The original Bukharian nuasch was Persian, I'd suspect that's the case for these guys too.